# Can I travel to UK with my Italian national spouse and my permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: uk, italian-residents, freedom-of-movement, permesso-di-soggiorno

I have an Italian permesso di soggiorno and I want to join my husband in the UK. My baby and my husband are Italian nationals. Can I travel with them with only the permesso di soggiorno?

Comment: Please upload a copy of your permesso di soggiorno

Comment: Depending on your citizenship, you’ll likely need an EEA family permit if you’re living in Italy with your Italian family member. You can check entry requirements using the tool on this website https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: Yes you can but only with your wife and you must need your country passport

Comment: Its showing like this: Do you have an Article 10 or 20 card?

You only get one of these if you’re both of the following:

•the family member of an EEA citizen
•living in a different EEA country than the one your family member is from.   what does its mean guys ?? ((We are living in italy))

Comment: Does your residence permit include this text: "carta di soggiorno di familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione" ?

Comment: That was written before on paper residence my is plastic mentioned motivi familiari only

Comment: Ahmed Gaber: the text beginning with "you only get one of these" is imprecise.  There are other conditions that they haven't named under which one can get such a card.  Living in a country that routinely issues them to family members of its own citizens is one such condition, and Italy is one such country as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Traveller as far as I'm aware, Italy typically issues article 10 cards to family members of EU citizens. – phoog 8 mins ago

Answer (score 6):

If your permesso di soggiorno says "Carta di soggiorno per familiari di cittadino dell'Unione" or anything like that then you can [go without a visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).  If it does not say that, then you will need an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the UK without a visa or family permit,  with your wife, if your card says "carta di soggiorno di familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione."  In that case it is an article 10 card.  It could also indicate *permanent* residence, in which case it's an article 20 card, but I don't know the exact wording in Italian.  It will certainly end with "di familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione."

If your card doesn't say one of those things, then you'll need a visa or, of your trip falls before the end of the transition period, an EEA family permit.

If your card truly says *permesso do soggiorno* rather than *carta di soggiorno* then it is probably not an article 10 or 20 card.

(This of course assumes that you do not hold a nationality that entitles you to enter the UK without a visa in your own right.  If you are, for example, a citizen of Canada, then you don't need a visa in any case.)